# how to find a node by if there are duplicate nodes

Tags: c#, devexpress, treelist

in Devexpress Treelist. i have duplicate data but it doesn't work well...

For example

1. List

   - im a student
   - im a nurse
   - we are friends
   - we are the world
   - these are not my money

## node that i want

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |
  ├───im
  │   └───a
  │       └───stuent
  │       └───nurse
  ├───we
  │   └───are
  │       └───friends
  │       └───the
  │           └───world
  │               └───0409

  ├───these
  │   └───are
  │       └───not
  │           └───my
  │               └───money
```

but my node is like this

## my node

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |
  ├───im
  │   └───a
  │       └───stuent
  │       └───nurse
  ├───we
  │   └───are
  │       └───friends
  │       └───the
  │           └───world
  │               └───0409
  │       └───not
  │           └───my
  │               └───money    
  ├───these
```

there is duplicate word "are" so when using FindNodeByFieldValue("B", "are")
every "are" words append under "we" not "these"

here is my code

```
treelist.AppendNode(new object[] { null, list[i].mean},
                                treelist.FindNodeByFieldValue("columnA", list[i].word));
```

Comment: well `FindNodeByFieldValue` finds the first node by that value, so you either have to search for nodes on a certain level, give unique names, or create your own custom node structure where its easy to add the nodes at the correct position.

Comment: is there any other way to search for nodes on a certain level?   or could you let me know how to create my own custom node structure? i tried before but it failed ;(

Comment: implement `IVirtualTreeListData` and bind your treeList to that object. If you want to find on a certain level you can use: `treeList.FindNode(x => x.Level >= 0 && x.GetValue("columnA").ToString() == list[i].word)`

Comment: you can also store some "uniqueId" in the Node.Tag property and then search the Node by that Tag